# nav-tabs in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Мой html код:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        <a href="" ng-click="changeActiveTab(tab.id)" data-toggle="tab" ng-bind="tab.label"></a>
        <div class="notify"><span>{{tab.count}}</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content csbi-body-bg" changeable-height>
    <div class="tab-pane fade csbi-body-work" ng-class="{'in active': isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
             ng-include="tab.templateUrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Angularjs:

```
$scope.tabs = [
        { id: 'unregistered', label: 'Незарегистрированные', templateUrl: '/Angular/Templates/Directions/Unregistered.html', count: 7 },
        { id: 'fromTO', label: 'Зарегистрированные из ТО/ЛО', templateUrl: '/Angular/Templates/Directions/RegisteredFromTO.html', count: 8 },
        { id: 'fromPOO', label: 'Зарегистрированные от ПОО', templateUrl: '/Angular/Templates/Directions/RegisteredFromPOO.html', count: 9 },
        { id: 'unassigned', label: 'Неназначенные', templateUrl: '/Angular/Templates/Directions/Unassigned.html', count: 27 },
        { id: 'assigned', label: 'В работе', templateUrl: '/Angular/Templates/Directions/InProcess.html', count: 19 }
    ];


$scope.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0].id;
    $scope.changeActiveTab = function (tab) {
        $scope.activeTab = tab;
        //do some work...
    };
```

Проблема в том что все табы загружают контент одновременно, т.е. там выполняется загрузка данных из базы, и она отрабатывает 5 раз. Как сделать чтобы контент загружался только при клике на таб?

Любые предложения.

Comment: Попробуйте добавлять свойство `templateUrl` для элемента массива `tabs` при клике на таб, в `changeActiveTab`.

Comment: Да спасибо, сработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал в итоге так:

html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
            <a href="" ng-click="changeActiveTab(tab.id)" data-toggle="tab" ng-bind="tab.label"></a>
            <div class="notify"><span>{{tab.count}}</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content csbi-body-bg" changeable-height>
    <div class="tab-pane fade csbi-body-work" ng-class="{'in active': isActiveTab(tab.id)}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        <div ng-if="tab.id == activeTab" ng-include="activeTabTemplateUrl" class="full-height">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

angularjs:

```
$scope.tabs = [
        { id: 'unregistered', label: 'Незарегистрированные', count: 7 },
        { id: 'fromTO', label: 'Зарегистрированные из ТО/ЛО', count: 8 },
        { id: 'fromPOO', label: 'Зарегистрированные от ПОО', count: 9 },
        { id: 'unassigned', label: 'Неназначенные', count: 27 },
        { id: 'assigned', label: 'В работе', count: 19 }
    ];

    $scope.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0].id;
    $scope.activeTabTemplateUrl = '/Angular/Templates/Directions/Unregistered.html';

    $scope.changeActiveTab = function (tab) {

        $scope.activeTab = tab;

        if ($scope.activeTab == 'unregistered') {
            $scope.activeTabTemplateUrl = '/Angular/Templates/Directions/Unregistered.html';
        }
        else if ($scope.activeTab == 'fromTO') {
            $scope.activeTabTemplateUrl = '/Angular/Templates/Directions/RegisteredFromTO.html';
        }
        else if ($scope.activeTab == 'fromPOO') {
            $scope.activeTabTemplateUrl = '/Angular/Templates/Directions/RegisteredFromPOO.html';
        }
        else if ($scope.activeTab == 'unassigned') {
            $scope.activeTabTemplateUrl = '/Angular/Templates/Directions/Unassigned.html';
        }
        else if ($scope.activeTab == 'assigned') {
            $scope.activeTabTemplateUrl = '/Angular/Templates/Directions/InProcess.html';
        }
    };
```